# Error while implementing Multi-Linear regression Using pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to implement 1 variable Linear regression using PyTorch. However i get [NaN] as output of my prediction when i train my model using large integer inputs .

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

class linearRegression(torch.nn.Module):            
    
    # instantiating Linear Regression class
    def __init__(self):
        super(linearRegression, self).__init__() 
        self.lr_pytorch = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)                 
    def forward(self,input_to_predict):                        
        predictions = self.lr_pytorch(input_to_predict)
        return predictions
            
    def fit(self,inputs,outputs,epochs = 10, learning_rate = 0.01):  
        
        inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array(inputs,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,1)))        
        labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array(outputs,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,1))) 
        
        stochastic_gradient_descent = torch.optim.SGD(self.lr_pytorch.parameters(),learning_rate)  
        mse_loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()                                                     
        
        for epoch in range(epochs):                                                                 
            stochastic_gradient_descent.zero_grad()
            predictions = self.lr_pytorch(inputs)
            
            loss = mse_loss_function(predictions,labels)
            loss.backward()
            stochastic_gradient_descent.step()
```

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20]
b = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,40]
c = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([150],dtype=np.float32)))

d = linearRegression()
d.fit(a,b,500)

prediction = d.forward(c) 

print(prediction)
```

The above block when executed gives the result
`tensor([299.9434], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)`

However, as soon as i change my last training example to 50 and it's output to 100 as below

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,50]
b = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,100]
c = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([150],dtype=np.float32)))

d = linearRegression()
d.fit(a,b,500)

prediction = d.forward(c) 

print(prediction)
```

I get the prediction as
`tensor([nan], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)`

Answer (score 0):

The gradients are getting too large. You could normalize the data or reduce the learning rate.

Comment: Thank you, reducing the learning rate solved the issue for me. If i increase the training variables even large, say 1000, then it requires further decreasing the Learning Rate. So looks like normalization is a better option.